# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' python 3.4 tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, box, tkinter-entry

I am calling my function mTime to get the values from 4 Entryboxes, to check the time, if there is a value my code works without a problem but if the entrybox is empty, just like '       ', I mean the user delete the default values in the entryboxes which are '0'. and leave it empty I want to assign a value of '0' if this happens

but it is not working!

my code

```
def mTime():
  if (len(str(Days_T.get())) == 0):
    dd = Days_T.set(0)
  else:
    dd = Days_T.get()
  if (len(str(Hours_T.get())) == 0):
    hh = Hours_T.set(0)
  else:
    hh = Hours_T.get()
  if (len(str(Minutes_T.get())) == 0):
    mm = Minutes_T.set(1)
  else:
    mm = Minutes_T.get()
  if (len(str(Seconds_T.get())) == 0):
    ss = Seconds_T.set(0)
  else:
    ss = Seconds_T.get()
  d = dd
  h = hh
  m = mm
  s = ss
  print (dd,hh,mm,ss)

Days_T = IntVar()
Hours_T = IntVar()
Minutes_T = IntVar()
Seconds_T = IntVar()

TDays = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Days_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=520,y=260)
THours = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Hours_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=550,y=260)
TMinutes = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Minutes_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=580,y=260)
TSeconds = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Seconds_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=610,y=260)

mTime()
```

I am getting this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Project\ManualTab.py", line 908, in mTime
    if (len(str(Minutes_T.get())) == 0):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 358, in get
    return getint(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**EDITED**

NEW CODE

```
  ddays = StringVar()
  ddays.set(Days_T.get())
  hhours = StringVar()
  hhours.set(Hours_T.get())
  mminutes = StringVar()
  mminutes.set(Minutes_T.get())
  sseconds = StringVar()
  sseconds.set(Seconds_T.get())
  if (len(ddays) == 0):
    dd = Days_T.set(2)
  else:
    dd = Days_T.get()
  if (len(hhours) == 0):
    hh = Hours_T.set(0)
  else:
    hh = Hours_T.get()
  if (len(mminutes) == 0):
    mm = Minutes_T.set(0)
  else:
    mm = Minutes_T.get()
  if (len(sseconds) == 0):
    ss = Seconds_T.set(0)
  else:
    ss = Seconds_T.get()  
  d = dd
  h = hh
  m = mm
  s = ss
  print (dd,hh,mm,ss)

Days_T = IntVar()
Hours_T = IntVar()
Minutes_T = IntVar()
Seconds_T = IntVar()

TDays = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Days_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=520,y=260)
THours = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Hours_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=550,y=260)
TMinutes = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Minutes_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=580,y=260)
TSeconds = Entry(mGui, textvariable = Seconds_T, width = 4, justify = CENTER).place(x=610,y=260)

mTime()
```

**BUT IS NOT WORKING**

Comment: You're setting `textvariable` to an `IntVar`. Use a `StringVar`.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi do add that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem a long time ago, but never put the answer here, anyway I used try and exempt to get and set a value to those entry boxes

here the code

```
    try:
        Days_T.get()
    except ValueError:
        Days_T.set(0)
        mGui.update()
    try:
        Hours_T.get()
    except ValueError:
        Hours_T.set(0)
        mGui.update()
    try:
        Minutes_T.get()
    except ValueError:
        Minutes_T.set(0)
        mGui.update()
    try:
        Seconds_T.get()
    except ValueError:
        Seconds_T.set(0)
        mGui.update()
    d = Days_T.get()
    h = Hours_T.get()
    m = Minutes_T.get()
    s = Seconds_T.get()
```

then I do not need to worry if the entry boxes are empty, it will just assign 0 if thay happens

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `textvariable` to an `IntVar`. Use a `StringVar`.

Comment: it is a timer, so numbers are only allowed here not any character, that's why I use Int instead of String

Comment: @Jose Sounds like you want to is validate the entry's input. For more information on that you should look at [Bryan Oakley's explanation of it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/3714930), [the New Mexico Tech page for it](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry-validation.html) and [effbot's explanation and example](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-entry-validate.htm).

Comment: Then cast the desired integers to strings and set them properly as `StringVar`.

Comment: do you mean                                                                                              ddays = StringVar()
  ddays = str(Days_T.get())
  if (len(ddays) == 0):
    dd = Days_T.set(10)
  else:
    dd = Days_T.get() and IT IS NOT WORKING

Comment: `ddays = StringVar()     ddays.set(Days_T.get())`

Comment: Where is `ddays` by the way?